# How to manually specify HEX colors in categorial scatter plot using Plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, hex, scatter-plot

I am trying to change the colors to my scatter plot using hex codes.
I need to assign the following hex color codes to my 3 categories:
"#581D74", "#4BA8B6" and "A7C673"

This is the code i have used:
For now I used a discrete pallette available on Plotly express

```
fig9 = px.scatter(df, x="ApplicantIncome", y="LoanAmount", color ="Property_Area", trendline = "ols",
                  color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Prism,
                  labels={
                    "ApplicantIncome": "Applicant Monthy Income",
                     "LoanAmount": "Loan Amount",
                     "Property_Area":"Property Area",
                 },
              title="Loan Amounts Based on Applicants Income and Property Area")

fig9.update_layout({
    'plot_bgcolor': 'rgba(255,255,255,255)',
    'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(255,255,255,255)'
})

fig9.show()
```

and the output is okay but i really need the exact hex color codes, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hex color codes in a list as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

fig = px.bar(df, y="continent", x="pop", color="continent", orientation="h", hover_name="country",
             color_discrete_sequence=["#581D74", "#4BA8B6", "#A7C673","#581D74", "#4BA8B6"],
             title="Explicit color sequence"
            )

fig.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, yes i have done this and it works !